# Flex Popup Button Question

Tags: apache-flex

Banging my head against the wall here. I don't want to reinvent the wheel.

The default Flex 3 classs for PopupButton is a combination of two buttons. One is a normal button with label and/or icon, and the second is the arrow which opens the popup.

My struggle here is that I just want a button with an icon that opens the popup directly, without having to write all the popup handling code all over again. The plan was to override the PopupButton class with, say, a new class called SimplePopupButton. This class would just hide the arrow, and point the button click handler to open the popup.

Seems simple, but I don't see an easy way to do this. Suggestions? Alternatives?

---

[**Edit**] I want a 16x16 icon button that opens a popup. PopupButton shipped with flex has two buttons: "It contains a main button and a secondary button, called the pop-up button, which pops up any UIComponent object when a user clicks the pop-up button." ([source](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/index.html)). I want the main button to open the popup, and hide the popup-button. (or vice-versa)

Comment: Do you want to change the current down arrow icon to be your own or get rid of it completely?

Comment: Either override the arrow and hide the primary button, or hide the arrow and put my icon in the primary button. I effectively want a button with a popup, and not the pair system adobe uses for popupButton, popupButtonMenu, and ComboBox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried setting a [new skin](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/flex_skins.html)? Not sure if it would work but it would be far easier than trying to write a new control.

Comment: I'm not clear on how a skin might solve this issue, since it's a behavior problem (albeit masked as a style concern). Can a skin for a PopupButton hide the drop-down arrow?

Comment: Turns out this is the best idea. A simple image skin does hide both parts of the button in lieu of the skin. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In Flex 3.4, the PopUpButton control has an attribute called "[openAlways](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/controls/PopUpButton.html#openAlways)", which, if set to true, allows the main button to open the popUp as well. Then, as mentioned before, simply set the skin of the button to hide the down-arrow.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I did some work with Flex, but here's my idea:

Create a new component consisting of a classic button and a list. The component should have two view states. The list should not be visible in the base state, but should become visible when the component enters the other state. The other state is, of course, entered on the click of the button. You can set the list to be initially positioned so that it's bottom left corner is aligned with the buttons's bottom left corner. Then create a transition from base state to the other state that would make the list do a "slide down" as it does in a standard PopuButton control. You can do this by simultaneously using a wipeup effect and a move effect in which you move the list on its y axis until it's top left corner is where it's bottom left corner was. Name the component MyPopupButton or whatever you wish to call it. For returning to the base state simply do a reverse on these effects.
As for the handling code - your app, of course, only needs to know what the user chose from the list, so that's no more code than usual. 

Hope this was helpful.

Comment: This is what I meant by reinventing the wheel. I'd have to manage the popup events and the positioning which are already handled in the popupbutton control. I'm trying to avoid all that hassle. Doing that and I might as well, like you said, write my own control. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

Um, I may be being a total idiot here, but why can't you just use a ComboBox? I mean the action on it is essentially the same as a popup button without the arrow button separation? Or am I being daft here.

Comment: Combo box is a form element that provides selection options. I want a popup that doesn't necessarily mean a simple list of items. I might want the popup to be a calendar control. This is why PopupButton is better than, say, PopupButtonMenu, or ComboBox.

Answer (score 0):

Try the popup property found 
[here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/201/langref/mx/controls/PopUpButton.html#popUp). It should be set to your popup.

```
print(</mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
          import mx.controls.Alert;
          public var myAlert:Alert = new Alert();
     ]]>
    </mx:Script>
    <mx:popUpButton popUp="{myAlert}" label="Button"/>
```

);

Comment: The problem isn't *what* to popup. The problem is making the control look like a simple button without the down-arrow. So the main button part should open the popup with the "click" event, and the arrow should not be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

this is sort of a designer hack, but I just set the following properties on my popUp button... (or you could create a style if you want to reuse)

Assuming you just want a 16x16 icon to popUp a menu when clicked...

```
<mx:PopUpButton icon="@Embed(source='pathToIcon.png')" arrowButtonWidth="16" paddingLeft="0" paddingRight="0" width="16" height="16" popUp="{menu}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

kind of a nasty hack but I did something much like Matt above that seems to work/look alright.

in CSS.

```
.camButtons
{
    padding-left:0;
    padding-right:1;
    up-skin: Embed(source="/assets/images/skins.swf", symbol="Button_ChatRoomControlsOver");
    over-skin: Embed(source="/assets/images/skins.swf", symbol="Button_ChatRoomControls");
    down-skin: Embed(source="/assets/images/skins.swf", symbol="Button_ChatRoomControls");
    disabled-skin: Embed(source="/assets/images/skins.swf", symbol="Button_ChatRoomControls");

    pop-up-up-skin: Embed(source="/assets/images/skins.swf", symbol="Button_ChatRoomControlsOver");
    pop-up-down-skin: Embed(source="/assets/images/skins.swf", symbol="Button_ChatRoomControls");
    pop-up-over-skin: Embed(source="/assets/images/skins.swf", symbol="Button_ChatRoomControls");
}

<mx:PopUpButton width="38" popUpGap="0" paddingLeft="37" arrowButtonWidth="38" id="flirts_btn" popUp="{flirts_menu}" styleName="camButtons" icon="@Embed(source='/assets/images/skins.swf', symbol='Icon_WinkOver')" downIcon="@Embed(source='/assets/images/skins.swf', symbol='Icon_WinkOver')" disabledIcon="@Embed(source='/assets/images/skins.swf', symbol='Icon_Wink')" toolTip="Send Flirt to User" buttonMode="true" useHandCursor="true" />
```

.... the important parts...

```
pop-up-up-skin: Embed(source="/assets/images/skins.swf", symbol="Button_ChatRoomControlsOver");
    pop-up-down-skin: Embed(source="/assets/images/skins.swf", symbol="Button_ChatRoomControls");
    pop-up-over-skin: Embed(source="/assets/images/skins.swf", symbol="Button_ChatRoomControls");


width="38" popUpGap="0" paddingLeft="37" arrowButtonWidth="38"
```